# Kinematic Rigidbody parented to a moving Rigidbody gets displaced

Tags: unity, c#, physics, movement, rigidbody

I have a kinematic Rigidbody parented to another non-kinematic moving Rigidbody. Render-wise, the child Rigidbody does not jitter, nor does it inherit any displacement changes from the parent Rigidbody. Nonetheless, when a Trigger callback occurs (Enter/Exit/Stay) it happens far from the object.

To debug, I am drawing a ray from the center to the cube (default Unity cube). It draws exactly from the center if the parent Rigidbody does not move; however, if I displace the parent Rigidbody the center seems to move, as shown in the following screenshot (NOTE: The red line was painted on Paint). If I stop the parent, the ray is drawn from the center of the cube as it should

[image: Ray Debugging]

Both Rigidbodies are setup as follows:

**Parent's Rigidbody Settings (Dark cube):**

- Non-Kinematic
- Gravity disabled
- Interpolation Mode: Interpolate
- Collision Detection: Discrete

**Child's Rigidbody Settings (Gray cube):**

- Kinematic
- Gravity disabled
- Interpolation Mode: None
- Collision Detection: Discrete

I have also tried changing the Interpolation modes and position constraints on each Rigidbody with no success. I am testing with the following code:

```
public class TEST_CompoundRigidbodies : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rigidbody;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody childRigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 72;
        Extensions.SetPhysicsFrameRate(72);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(rigidbody == null || childRigidbody == null) return;

        rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.transform.position + (Vector3.right * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
        Debug.DrawRay(childRigidbody.transform.position, Vector3.up * 5.0f, Color.cyan);
    }
}


public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetPhysicsFrameRate(int frameRate)
    {
        float dt = 1.0f / (float)frameRate;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = dt;
    }
}
```

**Why it seems I need to stick with a parented kinematic Rigidbody:**

I am using Unity's XR Interaction Toolkit. In order for interactions to happen, trigger interactions must happen, so I need that either the VR hands (interactors) or interactables have attached a Rigidbody.

**Thinks that I haven't yet Tried:**

- Attaching Rigidbodies to the hands (XRInteractors) instead: It would solve the issue for the interactables, but it would pass the problem into the hands.
- Make some sort of component that displaces the child Rigidbody equal to the displacement delta of a reference parent (quick example of the idea on the following code snippet). While I think it may work for the collider, it would displace the object, which would be also wrong.

  ```cs
  public class Example : MonoBehaviour
  {
      [SerializeField] private Rigidbody reference;
      private Rigidbody rigidbody;
      private Vector3 lastPosition;
      private Vector3 originalLocalPosition;

      private void Awake()
      {
          rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
          originalLocalPosition = transform.localPosition;
      }

      private void FixedUpdate()
      {
          if(reference == null) return;

          Vector3 d = reference.transform.position - lastPosition;

          transform.localPosition = originalLocalPosition + d;

          lastPosition = reference.transform.position;
      }
  }
  ```

Please let me know if I may provide more information, and thank you beforehand.

**EDIT**
I recenty discovered Unity's Physics Debugger, and indeed the collider displaces:

[image: Screenshot with Physics Debugger]

Comment: I notice you're drawing your ray in FixedUpdate, which runs before the physics step. So the changes to the location of the physics body may not have yet propagated back to the child transform. If you draw your ray in Update, after the physics step, does the problem still occur?

Comment: yeah, you are actually correct. The ray seems in place, though I am still having the real issues with the XR interactions (I am supposedly doing everything inside the Physics' thread).

Comment: There's no physics thread in Unity. Physics runs on the main thread. Want to edit the question to clarify the specific XR interaction problems you're having?

Comment: Well, by physics thread I am talking about FixedUpdate()...